# Combine multiple streams of events

Tags: java, algorithm, events

Suppose I have *N* streams of data events and I would like to combine them into one, using some for of ordering (*timestamp* for instance). Let's say `EventStream` is defined to be:

```
class EventStream{

    Event peek();

    Event next();
}
```

Now I would like to take *N* event streams, wrap them in one stream, which would enforce ordering. However, I don not want to simply iterate through all streams and add them into a `priorityQueue` - I do not want all events in the memory, as I will quickly run out of heap space. I would like a dynamic approach, in which the combined stream after each `next()` figures out what the next event should be. I could scan through *N* streams each time and find out what the next value is, but is there a better approach?

Comment: Sounds like you want a sorted heap without sorting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid caching everything and doing too many lookups over the streams by only peeking at their heads, and doing so only when needed. I suggest you write a `MergedEventStream` similar to this one:

```
public class MergedEventStream implements EventStream {

    private ArrayList<EventStream> merged = new ArrayList<EventStream>();
    private int nextIndex = -1;

    public MergedEventStream(Collection<EventStream> toMerge) {
        merged.addAll(toMerge);
        findNext();
    }

    public Event peek() {
        if (nextIndex == -1 && findNext() == false) {
           throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
           Event e = merged.get(nextIndex).peek();
           return e;
        }
    }

    public Event peek() {
        if (nextIndex == -1 && findNext() == false) {
           throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else {
           Event e = merged.get(nextIndex).next();
           findNext();
           return e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * iterates over merged, and for each stream with an available event,
     * adds it to a sorted TreeMap<Event, Integer> (sorting by any event field; integer
     * is stream index in arrayList)
     * if set is not empty, returns 'true', and sets nextIndex to the stream index
     * otherwise, returns 'false', and sets nextIndex to -1
     */
    private boolean findNext() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can increase efficiency somewhat by keeping the TreeMap as an instance attribute and refreshing only those streams that you extract from.

Answer (score 2):

Use a MinHeap to store one Event from each event stream.

On `next()` pop out the top event off the heap (the value with the oldest time).

Then push in one event from the same EventStream which the event was retrieved from.

So there will only be one Event form each EventStream in the MinHeap.

You will nead to store the reference to the EventStream with the Event in the MinHeap.

This `next()` implementation will use O(log n) where 'n' is the number of EventStreams.

Note: it is expected that the EventStream's has sorted Events. Next() always returns the oldest event.

Comment: Isn't it exactly what I suggest in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. Unless N is large, it should be OK.

If N is really large, you could store the first event of each stream in a sorted collection, associated with the stream it comes from, and each time you remove an item from this sorted collection, you would add the next one from the stream it comes from.

Comment: #2 is the same thing I was suggesting - you beat me to the punch